# Use Style on list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, coding-style

I have a list like this:

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}
```

I want to color all the 0's in red, but I dont want to count through all the elements, like in my solutions, which seems awefully complicated:

```
Table[If[list[[x]] == 0, Style[list[[x]], Red], list[[x]]], {x, 1, Length@list}]
```

How else could I do this without using Table? In other words, a simpler way, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list /. (0) :> Style[0, Red]
```